# HTML/CSS/JS(maybe) issue with Blogspot

Tags: javascript, html, css, blogspot

I'm helping out a friend with an issue with their blog, and can't for the life of me figure out the error.

http://theglamshack.blogspot.com/

Somewhere within the code, between the body it is managing to place 50000 or so pixels. I can't manage to locate WHERE it is coming from, aside from the fact that body min-height is 100% (which I cant find anywhere in the code at all.. ) I can't find any error.

If I could get some help tha'td be great!

Answer (score 1):

Under #sidebar-wrapper-left, the div that has classes "widget-content list-label-widget-content" is the one causing the issue.

Every for every list item contained in the unordered list is adding a few hundred pixels to the height. All of them added up is how you get a height of 50K.

The strange part is, the left-sidebar isn't really visible. If you don't need the left sidebar you could just set #sidebar-wrapper-left to display:none to see how it looks until you figure out how to remove it from the layout altogether.

**Update:**

It's easy to diagnose this using Chrome. Right click on the blank section below the body and hit 'Inspect Element' then mouseover the HTML elements in the code and their width/height values will popup.

Keep moving down the list until you find the lowest element that has a width > 50K and that shows you the section causing the problem (ie the one I outlined above).

Answer (score 0):

Check the DIV `sidebar-wrapper-left` and the other divs/content inside CSS inside it. Use FireBug a debugging tool to find out more info on what's wrong.

Answer (score 0):

You have "Label Widget" that is causing that problem. Remove it from your layout and you should be fine.